# AI derive new sentences from knowledge base using resolution rules

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

So I have a homework from university it is an AI lecture. Basically I need derive new logical statements from a knowledge base (kb) using resolution rules there is 6 test cases. 1-4 test cases gives correct answer but the 5th and 6th does not. 5th test case output should be: empty, nothing but it is frozenset({'C', 'A'}). For the 6th one it should be around 75 new sentences but it is around 40. How do I fix that this is the code: ( I also attached the homework task )

```
def resolve(ci, cj, kb):
    """Apply the resolution rule on two clauses ci and cj."""
    resolvents = []
    for literal in ci:
        if ('-' + literal) in cj:
            # remove the two literals that resolve
            resolvent = set(ci) | set(cj)
            resolvent.remove(literal)
            resolvent.remove('-' + literal)
            # check if the resulting clause is valid
            if not any([l in resolvent and '-' + l in resolvent for l in resolvent]):
                # check if the resolvent is already in the KB
                if resolvent not in kb:
                    resolvents.append(frozenset(resolvent))
    return resolvents


def get_all_resolvents(kb):
    """Derive all possible resolvents from the given knowledge base."""
    all_resolvents = set()
    # create a set of all possible pairs of clauses in the knowledge base
    clause_pairs = [(ci, cj) for i, ci in enumerate(kb) for cj in kb[i+1:]]
    # apply the resolution rule on each pair of clauses and add the resulting clauses to all_resolvents
    for (ci, cj) in clause_pairs:
        new_clauses = resolve(ci, cj, kb)
        for clause in new_clauses:
            if clause not in kb and clause not in all_resolvents:
                all_resolvents.add(clause)
    # check for contradictions in the knowledge base
    for clause1 in kb:
        for clause2 in kb:
            if clause1 != clause2:
                resolvent = clause1 | clause2
                # check if the resolvent is the empty clause
                if not resolvent:
                    return set()
    return all_resolvents


# Example knowledge base
# 1 test case
#kb = [set(['A', 'B', '-C']), set(['-C', '-B', 'A', 'D'])]

# 2 test case
#kb = [set(['A', 'B', '-C']), set(['C', '-B'])]

# 3 test case
#kb = [set(['A', 'C', 'D']), set(['A', 'B', 'C']), set(['C', '-B'])]

# 4 test case
#kb = [set(['A', 'C']), set(['A', 'B', 'C']), set(['C', '-B'])]

# 5 test case
kb = [set(['A']), set(['A', 'B', 'C']), set(['C', '-B'])]

#6 test case
"""
kb = [set(['DP','SP','KP']),
    set(['DA', 'SA', 'KA']),
    set(['DV', 'SV', 'KV']),
    set(['DP', 'DA', 'DV']),
    set(['SP', 'SA', 'SV']),
    set(['KP', 'KA', 'KV']),
    set(['-DP', '-SP']),
    set(['-DP', '-KP']),
    set(['-SP', '-KP']),
    set(['-DA', '-SA']),
    set(['-DA', '-SA']),
    set(['-DA', '-KA']),
    set(['-SA', '-KA']),
    set(['-DV', '-SV']),
    set(['-DV', '-KV']),
    set(['-SV', '-KV']),
    set(['-DP', '-DA']),
    set(['-DP', '-DV']),
    set(['-DA', '-DV']),
    set(['-SP', '-SA']),
    set(['-SP', '-SV']),
    set(['-SA', '-SV']),
    set(['-KP', '-KA']),
    set(['-KP', '-KV']),
    set(['-KA', '-KV']),
    set(['-DP']),
    set(['-DV']),
    set(['-SV']),
      ]"""
# derive all possible resolvents from the knowledge base
all_resolvents = get_all_resolvents(kb)
counter = 0
# Print all the derived sentences
for sentence in all_resolvents:
    print(sentence)
    counter = counter + 1

print(counter)
```

5 test case: empty
6 test case: around 75

Comment: Hi Tavo, resolution and formal logic can be tricky to get exactly right, my suggestion is writing many tests for your `resolve` function in isolation to understand if the bug is there or in the rest of the code. Furthermore, if you do not know how, I suggets downloading Pycharm or VScode and learning to use the debugger tool to see the values of all the variables at any point in the execution. Another suggestion is adding `from pprint import pprint` and `pprint(locals())` at critical points to see the values of all the variables. If you do please post that info here to help users help you.